# setText() not reflecting changes when called from another thread

Tags: javafx-2, scenebuilder, java-threads

I am a beginner in javaFX and am stuck in this one area. Any help will be appreciated a lot.
This is sample app I have made for clear understanding using scene builder. There is a text area and a button.I want to set data into the text area on the button click. The setting happens in another thread.
The code is as follows:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TpController{

    @FXML
    private ScrollPane scrollPane;

    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @FXML
    public TextArea txtArea ;

    private Stage stage;

    public void setTextArea(TextArea txt)
    {
        this.txtArea = txt ;
    }
    public TextArea getTextArea()
    {
        return txtArea;
    }

    public void setStage(Stage stage)
    {
        this.stage = stage;
    }

    public Stage getStage()
    {
        return stage;
    }
    public void setTopText(String text) {
       // set text from another class
       txtArea.setText(text);
    }

public void buttonHandler()
{

    tpThread t = new tpThread();
    t.start();
}
```

The tpThread class is as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class tpThread extends Thread {

@Override
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Justtp.fxml"));
try {
    Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
    } 
catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
TpController myController = loader.getController();
TextArea t =  myController.getTextArea();
String data = "hi\nhello\nhow are you\nnice to meet you\nhahaha";

//System.out.println(t.setData("hi"));
myController.setTopText(data);
}
```

Instead of using setTopText, i have also directly used

```
t.setText(data);
```

But no use. My final output does nothing on the button click.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with your code.

1. Modifications to the active scene graph off of the JavaFX application thread must be performed via [`Platform.runLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).
2. You don't need another thread to accomplish something on a button click.

   - You can just define an action handler for the button using [`setOnAction()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#setOnAction-javafx.event.EventHandler-).
   - Event handler methods on controllers can also be [cross-referenced in FXML via `onAction="#handleButtonAction"` where `handleButtonAction` is defined as a `public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event)` method in your controller](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#event_handler_attributes).
   - All event handlers are invoked by the JavaFX runtime on the JavaFX application thread, so you don't need to worry about multi-threading when writing event handlers - the JavaFX event handling programming model is single threaded.
3. Loading an FXML as you do in your code and not attaching the resultant node to a scene is pointless as the user will never see anything that is not attached to a scene.

There may be other issues with your code which cause it not to work as you expect.

In general, for assistance debugging an issue, provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Note it should be both *minimal* and *complete* so that somebody could copy and paste the code to replicate the issue (and pretty much nothing else).